# javascript for loop working in console but not working in div using its id

Tags: javascript

I have a input if I put a value in it and click the button all even number will show. my problem is it is working in console.log() but I am not able to show the numbers in a div using div id.

```
<input id="number" type="text" name="number">
<button onClick="checkeven()" id="chkeven">check even</button>
<div id="shownumber"></div>

<script>
function checkeven(){               
  var inputnumber = document.getElementById("number").value; 
  for(x=0; x<=inputnumber; x= x+2)
  {             
    document.getElementById("shownumber").innerHTML= x; 
    console.log(x);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Add a plus `+=` so it becomes `document.getElementById("shownumber").innerHTML += x;`

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=`. You are overwriting the previous number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the content of div `shownumber` with every iteration. you can build your output in a variable then use it to set the html content

```js
function checkeven(){

var inputnumber = document.getElementById("number").value; 
var finalHTML = '';

inputnumber = parseInt(inputnumber, 10) || 0;
for(x=0; x< inputnumber; x= x+2){
  finalHTML += `${x}<br/>`; 
 }
 
 document.getElementById("shownumber").innerHTML = finalHTML;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="text" name="number">
<button onClick="checkeven()" id="chkeven">check even</button>
<div id="shownumber"></div>
```